# how to read data from other Waves Oracles?

Tags: wavesplatform

how to read data from other Waves Oracles?

`getInteger(OracleAddress, key)`

key is String
I don't know in what type OracleAddress i should convert to

I tried

```
let OracleAddress = Address("3NAcoeWdUTWn8csXJPG47v1Fjtjcfqxb5tu".toBytes())
```

but doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

When you do `toBytes()` with string value you actually get bytes from UTF8 string, but in your case address is an array of bytes converted to base58, so you only need to decode it from base58:

```
let OracleAddress = Address(base58'3NAcoeWdUTWn8csXJPG47v1Fjtjcfqxb5tu')
getIntegerValue(OracleAddress, key)
```